# Commit solution in one tfs to another

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

We currently have a local TFS in our company and client needs me to check in the changes of a solution on my computer which to connected to our local TFS to their TFS online for deployment. I have all the persimmons to access it but not sure how to commit data to it.

Can I know how to do that.

The workspace that is mapped to our local TFS is C:\SourceControl

thanks in advance

Comment: One option is to create another workspace (mapped to a different directory) connected to your client's TFS instance. Copy your code from C:\SourceControl to the local directory of the client's workspace and check in from there. You now have two different copies of the same code, but that's the price you might have to pay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- create a new workspace
- copy the source code to the new workspace
- connect to VSO in Team Explorer and select the team project your client wants to use
- check in your source code

More information of how to start VSO, you can refer to the link: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/overview-of-get-started-tasks-vs.aspx